# Why is gstreamer not finding pulsesrc and how can I fix it?

Tags: 16.04, pulseaudio, gstreamer

The following command gives an error message:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -m pulsesrc ! audioconvert ! audiorate ! audioresample ! deepspeech silence-threshold=0.3 silence-length=20 ! fakesink
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "pulsesrc"
```

I have installed gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio, pulseaudio, gstreamer1.0-plugins-good. The documentation I found says pulsesrc is in gst-plugins-good, but there is no such package in the xenial repository.

Comment: I'm having the same issue in 18.04